# Chrome stucks after 30 or 40 minutes of work

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

In my tests chrome stucks after 30 or 40 minutes of work with error:

```
[710.758][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

My current functionally is to take some txt data from web page and add it to inputs using executeScript. Can someone to help with this issue? Or just tell me correct way to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, Chrome uses its own task manager... it can be opened by pressing shift+esc, assuming you don't have another program hooking that hotkey pair. Open the task manager and monitor the different tasks to see which one is bogging.

(couldn't leave a comment with low rep)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this kind of error happens when you have something on the browser side which is preventing the part of Selenium that lives in the browser from doing its work. Whenever I've seen it, it was because some code went into an infinite loop. This would prevent the JavaScript engine from giving control to anything else and would prevent Selenium from being able to poll the renderer.

Besides the message `Unable to receive message from renderer` the other symptom would be a relatively high CPU usage from the test browser. Linux was pretty good about preventing the runaway browser from completely hosing my machine. I had to take a look specifically at the browser's processes to see the problem.